# Input y BD (html/php): palabras con mayúsculas

Tags: base-de-datos, input

Quería consultar, de qué manera puedo lograr que el usuario, al momento de ingresar sus nombres (en input), independientemente de cómo los escriba, la letra inicial de cada palabra quede en mayúsculas y, por ende, esto también aparezca en la base de datos.
Ejemplos:
Usuario: Luciano miguel / Debería ser: Luciano Miguel
Usuario: luciano miguel / Debería ser: Luciano Miguel
Usuario: LUCIANO MIGUEL / Debería ser: Luciano Miguel
Usuario: Luciano MIGUEL / Debería ser: Luciano Miguel
y así...
La idea es que se mientras el usuario escribe, esto vaya siendo vist. Lo haría en onKeyUp
Estoy viendo por varias publicaciones, pero no logro el objetivo. Les comparto el último código, en JS, que encontré, pero las mayúsculas no las modifica y en la base de datos tampoco.
Gracias.

```
    function mayusculas(aqui){
    palabras=aqui.value.split(" ");
    for(a=0;a<palabras.length;a++){
        letra=palabras[a].charAt(0);
        palabras[a] = letra + palabras[a].substring(1 , palabras[a].length).toLowerCase();
        
    }
    texto="";
    for(a=0;a<palabras.length;a++){
        if(a>0){texto+=" ";}
        texto+=palabras[a];
    }
    aqui.value=texto;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

¡Hola Luciano! Leí tu problema y logré dar con una solución que por lo menos a mí me funciono y espero que a ti también te pueda ayudar ;).

Aquí te dejo los códigos JS:

**1.** Primero, en caso de que el método **trim()** no exista nativamente, se escribe este código para crearlo, no es necesario hacerlo pero si quieres estar seguro de que funcione en todos los navegadores es mejor utilizarlo

```
 if (!String.prototype.trim) { 
  (function() {
    // Make sure we trim BOM and NBSP
    var rtrim = /^[\s\uFEFF\xA0]+|[\s\uFEFF\xA0]+$/g;
    String.prototype.trim = function() {
      return this.replace(rtrim, '');
    };
  })();
}
```

**2.** Javascript no tiene un método nativo para escribir la primera letra de un string en mayúscula(o por lo menos eso he leído), aquí pues definimos la función que hará ese trabajo. Esta función la utilizaremos en la función principal del punto **4**.

```
function MayusPrimeraLetra(string) {
  return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
}
```

**3.** Ahora definimos el input de tipo text que vamos a utilizar:

```
<input id="nombre" type="text" onkeyup="corregirNombre(this)">
```

**4.** El siguiente código es la función que hace todo el trabajo en el momento que *OnKeyUp* detecta actividad en el input.

```
    const corregirNombre = (string)=>{

        // Separamos el string del input y lo convertimos en un array
        var palabras = string.value.split(" ");
        var stringFinal; // Declaramos esta variable para que no nos de error

        // Si la longitud de palabras es distinta de uno quiere decir que se pudo separar
        if ( palabras.length != 1 ){

            // Redefinimos cada elemento del array en caso de que el usuario ingrese nombres raros
            for(var i = 0; i < palabras.length; i++){

                palabras[i] = palabras[i].toLowerCase();
                palabras[i] = MayusPrimeraLetra(palabras[i]);
        
            }

            // Con el método join() juntamos todos los elementos del nuevo array palabras
            stringFinal = palabras.join(' '); 
            document.getElementById('nombre').value = stringFinal; // asignamos el nuevo valor del input
        
        // Esto se hace para la primera palabra, ya que la longitud de la variable palabras es 1 hasta que el usuario aprete espacio,
        // por lo que no se le aplican los cambios respectivos del if superior. Con esto corregimos la primera palabra.
        }else if( palabras.length == 1 ) {

            stringFinal = string.value.toLowerCase();
            document.getElementById('nombre').value = MayusPrimeraLetra(stringFinal);

        } 
   
    
    }

    // LISTO ;)
```

Espero que te haya podido ayudar, un gran saludo colega :D

Comment: GRACIAS por el gran tiempo que te has tomado. Ahora... ¿puede ser qué no pase nada? No me estaría funcionando, aún copiando y pegando tus códigos y modificando el ID del INPUT. Tampoco me carga en la BD.

Comment: Vaya :( , voy a revisar bien mi código y veré si me equivoqué al escribir algo, porque de verdad que me funcionó, voy a revisarlo de todar formas, un gran saludo colega!

Comment: Lo probé recipen Luciano y sí me funciona ;(, probaste con el código tal cual estaba? debiese funcionar ;(. Y bueno quería preguntar si te arroja algún mensaje por consola o simplemente no dice nada , estoy atento a tus respuestas :)

Comment: Hola Benjamin (no te puedo arrobar)! Solucionado: tus códigos funcionan a la perfección y en la base de datos igual. Te pido disculpas, el error, obviamente era mío. Qué pasó? Tengo un archivo JS con todas las funciones que utilizo y ahí es donde se me presentaba el error. Tus códigos lo puse en un archivo JS nuevo y funcionó a la perfección. Simplemente GRACIAS por tu gran ayuda y, ojalá, otros la pueda aprovechar.

Comment: Genial Luciano!! Me alegro que te haya servido y bueno no te preocupes, a cualquiera le puede pasar eso :) , un placer haberte ayudado colega!! Éxitos :)